# How a contract stored in the blockchain?

Tags: architecture

I am very wondering how the contract code stored in the blockchain? I think the blockchain only contain a group of transactions and some meta data. Am I wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Contract is stored as EVM bytecode

http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/contracts-and-transactions/contracts.html

Comment: Is that meaning the bytecode is stored in the associated block?